# jQuery hover effect after click doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I want to have hover effect after click on my button. I used to do that jQuery elements array and probably there is a problem. My code is here so you can see how it works:

What is wrong?

```js
var lastclick = 0;
function clicked(x)
{
 if(lastclick!=0) $("#button")[lastclick-1].mouseleave();
 $("#button")[x-1].mouseenter();
 lastclick = x;
}

$(".1").click(function(){clicked(1);});
$(".2").click(function(){clicked(2);});
$(".3").click(function(){clicked(3);});
```

```css
#button {
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    margin: 20px;
}

#button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="button" class="1">
1
</div>
<div id="button" class="2">
2
</div>
<div id="button" class="3">
3
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bbxx8nk/) link

Comment: 1. Fix the link.  2. Bring the relevant code to the question directly, not just in a Fiddle.

Comment: Please describe the desired behavior.  "hover effect after click" - meaning do you want it to change colors and **stay changed**, regardless of hover? Or do you want a different hover effect than the one you have in place? Or something else?

Comment: Your code is really bad. Id's must be unique page wide (one element - one unique id), class names, shouldn't start with number.

Comment: Sory I can't fix the link because even after 4 spaces the error block my post... And yes I want to stay changed color after click.

Comment: OK now link is fixed.

Comment: "Probably there is a problem" What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe in this array: $("#button")[lastclick-1] but I don't know so that is why I am asking...

Answer (score 0):

I am still a little unclear on what you want. But here it is if I understood right. As other have mention you can not start an id with a number or some symbols. Second the id must be unique is like two people, no two people have the same id.

NOTE: You don't need javascript for this.

```css
.button{
    display: none;
}
.button + label{
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
  
    margin: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s;
       -moz-transition: background-color 0.25s;
            transition: background-color 0.25s;
}
.button:checked + label{
    
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="radio" class="button" name="set" id="button1"/>
<label for="button1">1</label>


<input type="radio" class="button" name="set" id="button2"/>
<label for="button2">2</label>


<input type="radio" class="button" name="set" id="button3"/>
<label for="button3">3</label>
```

Comment: I have 3 different classes inside my original buttons so only way is simulate the hover action after click. And only one button must be hovered at one time.

Comment: what do you mean you have 3 different classes inside your original buttons? That does not make sense. Just tell me what you want!

Comment: Sory , 3different divs  and each one has differetn class :) I want to simulate hover action because in css I have:
#button:hover .marginline
{
 transition: all 200ms ease;
 width: 5vw;
}

#button:hover #buttontext
{
 transition: all 200ms ease;
 color: rgba(50,50,50,1);
}
#button:hover .ikonka
{
 transition: all 200ms ease;
    fill: #ffffff;
}
So it is hard to change 3 classes at once so I want to simulete hover of mouse after click and clean hover after set different hover.